# Why isdigit() return false on float?

Tags: python, python-2.7, floating-point, digit

I would like to check if my value is a float with a point or a comma but isdigit() return false with a point. I would like to know why and how go through it.

```
> value = "0.0"
> print value.isdigit():
>>> False
```

My code is :

```
if "." in value and value.isdigit()
    print "ok"
```

Comment: Because `.` is not a digit. `isdigit()` only returns true for strings containing **only** digits.

Comment: This can't be true at any point, because the one thing can't be with the other.

Comment: but "0.0" is a float so for me it's a digit too or is it different ?

Comment: `"0.0"` is not a digit. `"0"` is a digit. `"0.0"` is a string containing two digits and a `"."` character. See http://www.dictionary.com/browse/digit, in particular, definition 3.

Comment: "digit" does not mean "number"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`str.isdigit()` will only return true if all characters in the string are *digits*. `.` is punctuation, not a digit.

From the Python 3 [`str.isdigit()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit):

> Formally, a digit is a character that has the property value Numeric_Type=Digit or Numeric_Type=Decimal

(For Python 2, for `str` objects only the ASCII digits (`0` through to `9`) are considered, but for `unicode` objects the same definition applies).

See the [official *Numeric Property definitions* specification](http://www.unicode.org/L2/L2012/12310-numeric-type-def.html); there are [708 Unicode codepoints](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/list-unicodeset.jsp?a=%5B%3Ant%3Ddigit%3A%5D%5B%3Ant%3Ddecimal%3A%5D&g=&i=) that match that description.

Simplifying this to general unicode categories, numeric types in Unicode have a category starting with `N`, but `.` does not:

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> unicodedata.category(u'.')
'Po'
```

`P` stands for *punctuation* here, `o` for *other*.

Vice-versa, strings that contain only digits are not always convertable to a float or number either:

```
>>> unicodedata.name(u'\u2080')
'SUBSCRIPT ZERO'
>>> unicodedata.category(u'\u2080')
'No'
>>> unicodedata.digit(u'\u2080')
0
>>> u'\u2080'.isdigit()
True
>>> float(u'\u2080')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'decimal' codec can't encode character u'\u2080' in position 0: invalid decimal Unicode string
```

So a subscript-zero is not really 0 as far as `float()` is concerned, but it *is* a digit.

If you want to test if a string is a valid floating point number, use `float` and catch the `ValueError`:

```
def is_float(string):
    try:
        float(string)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

Comment: Yes, always use exception name to catch respective exception in except block. +1